# How can I pull out / view scripts that are run using GTM Googletagmanager

Tags: google-tag-manager

The question is, how can I find out which scripts the contractor runs on my site through google tag manager? There is no access to the cabinet

Comment: Tell the contractor that you will fire them if they don't tell you want to need to know.  Given that the legal risk is yours, the idea that you don't know what runs in your site is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

1. What is the cabinet?
2. If you don't have access to the GTM container that's run on your site, request it immediately. You have to be the owner of the said container. If the full ownership access is not given to you immediately, eliminate the script from the site and fire the contractor. Start over.
3. There are basically three common ways to comfortably check for the third party scripts loaded through GTM:

a) Open **dev tools**. Note what's loaded in your **Network tab**, then block "gtm" in the **request blocker** of your dev tools and reload the page. Note the difference in **loaded scripts** of the Network tab. Repeat the same with the **DOM**, paying attention to the inline **scripts there**. Repeat on different pages. That would give you about **90%** of all that is usually loaded through GTM.

b) Go to your **GTM container**, and export it as **JSON** (you'll need to have **access** to the container). Open the said JSON and inspect everything that's there. You can look for any instance of "http" there, or things alike. It's still possible to obfuscate script load even further and you can start looking for things like `base64`, `atob`, `btoa` and `eval`, but that will only get you past about 99% of potential code obfuscation. It's still possible to eval code, say, with the Function constructor. I'm sure there are other ways too.

c) Finally, review every variable and tag manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I still didn't understand how to view the code of scripts that are being worked out on my site page via GTM. The contractor does not give access to the GTM container, as this is their company policy. At the moment, I haven't added the GTM code to my website yet. I have my own GTM container installed and I'm trying to find my scripts added to GTM on the site page, but when viewing the downloaded page code (developer mode in the browser) I don't see the when lines that are activated in GTM when the page loads.

Comment: Is it possible to view the script code running using GTM through a browser?

Comment: If that is the policy of their company, that company should have no clients. A policy of an independent company being able to run arbitrary JS on your site is abuse. As to how to view what's loaded - Look at my answer. Use the Network tab of the Chrome Debugger.

Comment: understood, thank you! I studied the example of my GTM according to your method, it's strange, but some scripts are visible, and some for some reason are not.

Comment: some scripts can be loaded from thisd party sources, some can be just shoved to the DOM inline <script> from the container, some can be just silently executed without being manifested in DOM or in Network via GTM's CJS variables. But that code can still be found via the code search function if you know what to search for. Finally, there also is this GTM Spy tool, but I haven't been able to get to it recently. Some people can acccess it though. If you can, you can use it to download the whole container with minified code and with no names.